# ¿Cargar imagen diferente cada vez que abro mi aplicación?

Tags: java, android, random, android-imageview

estoy tratando de hacer una app para niños.

[image: esta es la parte grafica.]

quiero que cuando el usuario abra la app,la cierre y vuelva abrirla ese imageview
que es la manzana se muestre otra fruta. para eso use un método random.

```
int num_aleatorio = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
```

su respectivo id

```
iv_personaje = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView_personaje);
```

estas son las condiciones para que se haga el cambio de imagenes dependiendo del
numero que me arroje el ramdon.

```
int id;
if (num_aleatorio == 0 || num_aleatorio == 10) {
        id = getResources().getIdentifier("mango", "drawable", getPackageName());
        iv_personaje.setImageResource(id);

    }
```

como pueden ver el nombre de la fruta es el nombre de la imagen que se encuentra
en la carpeta drawable.
asigne mas condiciones de estas mismas pero con diferentes números y nombres de frutas no las pongo porque la única diferencia son los números, los números están programados del 0 al 10.

entonces cuando la emulo la app se abre pero de vez en cuando a veces se cierra sola y el imageview no cambia. ¿en donde puedo buscar el error?

Comment: Que otros "drawable" deseas mostrar además de "mango" cuales son sus nombres?  En cuanto a tu pregunta ¿en donde puedo buscar el error? puedes buscar la info en el LogCat.Recuerda agregar titulos descriptivos a tu pregunta, revisa [ask],saludos.

Comment: (fresa,manzana,sandia,uva).estos son los nombres de las imágenes que pegue en la carpeta drawable.

Comment: Ok mauricio ¿deseas que aleatoriamente se muestre uno de esos elementos en tu pantalla inicial verdad?

Comment: exacto amigo asi es.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error se debe posiblemente a que estas cargando un valor que no existe.

**¿Como cargar una imagen aleatoriamente?**

Primeramente define un método para obtener un numero entero aleatorio en base a la cantidad de elementos:

```
public static int getRandom(int max) {
    return (int) ((Math.random() * (max + 1 - 0)) + 0);
}
```

ahora debes definir un array de elementos tipo entero en donde defines las imágenes

```
Integer[] verduras ={
        R.drawable.fresa,
        R.drawable.manzana,
        R.drawable.sandia,
        R.drawable.uva,
};
```

Los elementos posibles serían desde el indice 0 hasta el indice 3, 4 elementos en total de tu array, entonces simplemente llama tu método de esta forma para que obtenga una imagen aleatoriamente del array:

```
iv_personaje = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView_personaje);
iv_personaje.setImageResourceverduras[(getRandom(3)]);
```

de esta forma cada vez cargara una imagen aleatoria.

Comment: gracias por tu tiempo te agradezco