# Problemas con la vista diseño al agregar botones y editText

Tags: android-studio

estoy haciendo una app sencilla lo normal editText,texview botones etc. en la vista designe se ve así.

sin emular

[image: sin emular]

emulada con genymotion

[image: emulada]

aquí lo único que encontré en el LogCat

```
04-02 19:49:05.524 3917-3917/com.example.frutty E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.textclassifier.TextClassificationManager', referenced from method androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextClassifierHelper.getTextClassifier
```

es así tanto con relative layout y constrait layout.

aquí agrego el build.gradle.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

 android {
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.fruttyappdos"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'}
```

Comment: Que clases usas en tu app,. podrìas agregar tu build.gradle por favor?

Comment: ola amigo, discúlpame pero no estoy seguro cual es el build.gradle estuve consultando ¿el build.gradle es en donde se encuentra esta linea (compileSdkVersion 29)? responderme por favor

Comment: asi es! @mauricio , estoy pensando que el problema se debe a una dependencia, por cierto confirma si tu proyecto usa ya AndroidX -

Comment: ya lo agregue Jorgesys♦, lo del AndroidX no doy con ello,este android lo instale hace mes y medio y es muy incongruente. lo ves bien organizado en la vista diseño pero al emular aparecen todos los botones y componentes desubicados.

Comment: si usas Androidx @mauricio , puedes verlo en las dependencias, en que parte de tu código usas el método : getTextClassifier() si pudieras agregar esa clase

Comment: ola Jorgesys♦ discúlpame por la tardanza,de hecho no tengo ningun getTextClassifier() en cuanto el código es el mismo de esta pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/342268/cargar-imagen-diferente-cada-vez-que-abro-mi-aplicación recuerdas que tu me ayudastes.

Comment: amigo aqui el problema en todo esto no sera la vista diseño o la version de android? porque a veces se desaparecen las herramientas o atributos, el fondo  de la vista design se ve negra cuando no debería ser así